# Proxy authentication with terminal Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, command-line, apt, proxy, authentication

I would like to access the internet to update files etc. from the terminal on a secured proxy network. I've already tried the following:

1. Adding to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy`, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu`:

   ```
   Acquire::http::proxy "http://name:password@proxy_server:port";
   ```
2. `export http_proxy=http://name:password@proxy_server:port/` on a terminal.
3. Adding `export http_proxy=http://name:password@proxy_server:port/`to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

These were few of the major efforts. 
There are no spaces in my username nor are there any special characters in my password (especially "@"). I've double checked and all the information entered is correct. The info is correct because it works with the browser (Manual proxy in Network and authentication when first opened the browser). I've also tried by making the "p" in "proxy" into capitals but to avail. 
I always get the error:  `407  Proxy Authentication Required.`
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do ntlmaps (or cntlm) come from? Are they part of the install? But if they come from an internet store, how is this going to work if the internet connection is what's not working?

Answer (score 9):

Test this:

```
sudo su -
apt-get update
apt-get install ntlmaps
```

Configure it: domain, username, password, proxyserver.net, port

Files:
`/etc/bash.bashrc`

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865
export ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865
```

`/etc/environment`

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865
ftp_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865
```

`/etc/apt/apt.conf` (create the file if it does not exist)

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:5865";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:5865";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:5865";
```

Comment: Another option is to use cntlm: apt-get install cntlm. I have not measured, but cntlm is supposed to have better performance. This seems reasonable since cntlm is C and ntlmaps is Python

Comment: How can you download ntlmaps when you have no internet connection because you need to connect to a proxy?

Comment: Now `wget`,  `apt-get update`, and `apt-get upgrade` are not hanging, but `apt-get` is failing and `wget` is saying "Proxy request sent, awaiting response." Not sure what's going on. No one has a terminal solution at my work bc they all use the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

What you did (`export http_proxy=http://name:password@proxy_server:port/`) is actually pretty close to what works for me:

```
http_proxy="http://name:password@proxy_server:port/"
export http_proxy
```

I hope this works for you, too. ;)

Comment: This is exactly the same, just in two lines instead of one...

Comment: It works for me if I use quatation marks. Without it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your password has a special character that needs to be '[escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)', or be [encoded properly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) for a URL.

For example, the following characters need to be encoded (but there are many others):

- `#`
- `@`
- `%`

If your password contains special characters, be sure they are properly [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).